# how do add a link to an ActiveAdmin view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  show :title => :name do     
    attributes_table do
      row :username
      row :email
      row :last_request_at
      row :foo
    end
  end
end
```

and I want foo just make a `<a href="/foo">foo</a>` in the view.

So I define:

```
def foo
  <a href="/foo">foo</a>
end
```

in the user.rb model.  And it displays but the tag is escaped so it's not clickable.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try:

```
row :foo do
  link_to('foo','#')
end
```

and replace `'#'` with your route.

Answer (score 23):

if you are working with a has many you can loop through the list as well,
important is not too forget the `.html_safe`

```rb
    row "Bars" do |foo|
      foo.bars.each.map do |bar|
        link_to(bar.title, admin_bar_path(bar)) 
      end.join(', ').html_safe
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`= link_to 'List Users', admin_users_path` in your view should work. Check that your ActiveAdmin namespace is actually `admin` using `ActiveAdmin.application.default_namespace.to_s` (in the console) though.

Hope that helps someone.