# How to add a link back to resource index page from show in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, link-to

I am trying to add a link to the show of an ActiveAdmin resource, Volunteer_Details.

After editing a record in the model, there is no link to the index of that resource.

I know I can simply click the resource page link at the top, but I'd like to add a link in the show view of each record for convenience.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799566/how-do-add-a-link-to-an-activeadmin-view) and attempted to follow that method to add a link.

My code looks like this:

```
    show do
attributes_table do
  row :id
row 'Name' do |m|
    m.participant.first_name + ' ' +m.participant.last_name
end
row :date
row :importance
row :story
row :questions
row :created_at
row :updated_at
row 'Go Back' do
    link_to 'Volunteer Details', admin_volunteer_detail_path
   end

end


active_admin_comments
    end
```

If I am on this record `http://localhost:3000/admin/volunteer_details/4`

My code links back to this

The link that my show view creates links back to the page I am already on, and not `http://localhost:3000/admin/volunteer_details/

I would like the link to go back to the `volunteer_details` index page.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a link on the top resource links as,

```
action_item :view, only: :show do
  link_to 'Volunteer Details', admin_volunteer_details_path
end
```

or

```
row 'Go Back' do
    link_to 'Volunteer Details', admin_volunteer_details_path
   end

end
```

in your code

note that index path is not `admin_volunteer_detail_path` but it should be `admin_volunteer_details_path`